# DataLayer и woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

У меня стоит задача запушить в datalayer данные оформленного заказа для аналитики. Сайт стоит на вордпрессе и магазин сделан с помощью woocommerce. В данные нужно также запушить номер заказа, но на этапе оформления пользователем у меня еще нет этих данных, поэтому я пытаюсь получить его с хука и с помощью js передать в datalayer, когда пользователь нажмет "оформить заказ"

Я использую хук вот так:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_code_after_order_processed');
function custom_code_after_order_processed($order_id) {
    $orderNumber = esc_js($order_id);
// тут код js
}
```

И проблема в том, что он не работает совсем. Даже если напишу что-то типа:

```
function custom_code_after_order_processed($order_id) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let orderNumber = <?php echo esc_js($order_id); ?>;
        console.log('orderNumber:', orderNumber);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

То код тоже не работает, в консоль я ничего не получаю, но сам хук выводит весь этот код в консоль типа вот так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let orderNumber = 4574
    console.log('orderNumber:', orderNumber);
</script>
```

Он выводит код из функции и выводит номер заказа, заменяя php код, но сам js вообще не выполняет. В чем-то ошибка или как тут делать надо, чтоб js работал? Не понимаю, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Не знаю кто у тебя такой dataLayer, но в репо есть плагины https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/dataLayer

Comment: Я в целом все события уже вручную прописал и они нормально отрабатывают. У меня проблема только с этим последним событием, потому что мне нужно отловить еще и номер заказа, но когда я работаю с хуком, чтоб он еще и код js выполнил, когда создаст заказ, то он не выполняет вообще никакой js

Comment: а dataLayer - это массив данных для гугл аналитики, я в нем отправляю данные про заказ (название товаров, цены, количество)